# How to get month and year values from jquery datepicker in change function

Tags: jquery

can anyone tell me that how to get the Month and year value in onchange function and with out using `.datepicker({`

even the change function is not calling how can i get the value from the drop downs 
HTML:-

```html
<div class="dpicker" id="mnthyear"><input type="text" maxlength="10" id="SCAactionmonth" class="form-control formdatepicker"  aria-label="What month would you like this SCA action to be presented to the Service Contract Approval Review Board (SCARB)?" /></div>
```

```js
 $(document).on('change',".ui-datepicker-year",function (e) {
        var year=$(".ui-datepicker-year option:selected").text(); 
        $("#SCAactionmonth").text(year);
    })
```

Comment: Where is your code ? Show us what you have so far and tell us which part of code is not working. We do not have magic ball in our hand to guess your  problem.

Comment: Show us what you have yet!

Comment: $(document).on('change',".ui-datepicker-year",function (e) {
var year=$(".ui-datepicker-year option:selected").text();
$("#SCAactionmonth").text(year);
})

Comment: i need the value in the change function but this is not working even the change function is not calling

Comment: Please update your question above with the relevant code instead of a comment.

Comment: @BhavyaSruthi You already have it. Isn't it working ?

Comment: no it is not working the change is not calling

Comment: @BhavyaSruthi Is your code inside document ready ?

Comment: What is drop down and  how its related to date-picker ? Show your Html ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `option:selected`. You are using datepicker so it is applicable on input 
 type text .

```js
$('#datepicker').datepicker();
$(document).on('change', ".ui-datepicker-year", function(e) {
  var year = $(".ui-datepicker-year").text();
  $("#SCAactionmonth").text(year);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<input id="datepicker" type="datepicker" class='ui-datepicker-year' name="date" placeholder="Date" />

<label id='SCAactionmonth'></label>
```

But  I suggest to use datepicker change.

```js
$('#datepicker').datepicker()
    .on("change", function (e) {
        $('#SCAactionmonth').text($(this).val())
        
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<input id="datepicker" type="datepicker" name="date" placeholder="Date" />
<label id='SCAactionmonth'></label>
```

Comment: $('#datepicker').datepicker() this is not calling.... Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function

Comment: type="datepicker" is not working it showing ... the value of 'type' attribute is marked as invalide because its's not supported by current schema.  i have added the both scripts in my aspx file.

Comment: Load your jquery ui after jquery .